# Proper usage of OAuth2 scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization, access-control

I‘m confused about the usage of OAuth2 scopes.

From my understanding an OAuth2 scope is a permission granted *by* the end-user *to* an application to do something on their behalf.

However, I've come across tutorials and articles where people are using OAuth2 scopes to grant permissions to users for accessing restricted resources.

For example, an Azure AD admin is granting a scope to a user to enable them to edit documents. This seems like a workaround to achieve some kind of access control, rather than using OAuth2 scopes as they are intended to be used.

I’m new to the OAuth2 world and would appreciate any clarification on this topic to ensure that I am using scopes correctly

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

**Note** that: OAuth2 scopes are used to grant permissions to the Azure AD applications to access resources on behalf of the user.

- To grant permissions to users to access resources scopes can be used.
- OAuth2 scopes are used for permission management control and access control.

For sample, I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permission** like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, **`User.Read.All`** permission is present like this:

[image]

By using the above permissions, I am able to query the **users** like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

[image]

If I pass the same access token to query the **groups**, I got the **`403`** error like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standards based answer based on [RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3). OAuth is primarily about protecting data. Note that some authorization servers may add extra rules on top of this, but personally I like to stick to standards.

A scope is one (high level) mechanism for protecting data. If you have a `marketing` API and a `finance` API, then you might define two scopes named after the APIs. If an access token with only a marketing scope is sent to the finance API, it would be rejected with a 403 forbidden error. In this way you can set high level authorization boundaries.

When configuring clients, you can decide what scopes they are given. Eg, a marketing app would not be assigned a finance scope. If a user who had rights to financial data was using the marketing app, the token would not have access to financial data. In this manner, scopes enable apps to run with least privilege.

Scopes are fixed at design time. More generally they grant access to an area of data and permissions on that data, eg an administrator might define a `finance_read` scope and assign that to a client. In Azure AD this is what is happening - the scope is n
being assigned to a client, not a user.

For more dynamic and detailed authorization, use claims instead. These are fields issued to access tokens. They are evaluated per user at the time of token issuance. An example claim used for authorization in APIs might be `subscription_level=gold`.

In some scenarios, where personal assets are used, the user can be required to consent to use of scopes or claims before tokens are issued. Eg the built in `profile` scope contains various name related fields. A consent screen might enable the user to control which of these are issued to tokens, or to reomve the entire scope.